builder.Services.Configure is not called during startup
I try to set some configuration values during the startup before I configure Kestrel. I try to do this to use some settings from singleton and a ILogger during the configuration.
Simplified sample:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);

builder.Services.Configure<MyKestrelOptions>(optionsKestrel =>
{
    //Debugger nerver stops here
    var configService = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfigurationService>();
    var logger = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    KestrelStartup.BuildOptions(configService, optionsKestrel, null);
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>();

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    var optionsKestrel = context.Configuration.Get<KestrelOptions>();
    if (optionsKestrel != null)
    {
        optionsKestrel.Logger?.LogDebug("DEBUG POSSIBLE");
    }
});

public class KestrelOptions
{
    public String? ServerPfxPath { get; set; }
    public ILogger? Logger { get; set; }
}

While Debugging I never stopped in the Configure lamba. And optionsKestrel.Logger is allways null.
How to achieve this as I need some configuration settings to be read in ConfigurationService for configure Kestrel and what to log during some callbacks (ClientCertificateValidation) configured in builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel.

MyKestrelOptions - is it a typo?

OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure registers the some config via the options pattern in the DI. To get the options registered via Configure you need to resolve one of the option interfaces via DI (for example IOptions<KestrelOptions>).
On the other hand ConfigurationBinder.Get just binds the configuration (from different sources registered for the app) to some destination class, that's it, it does not use DI or options pattern.

I need some configuration settings to be read in ConfigurationService

One option to consider is to look into creating custom configuration provider
P.S.
builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider() - you should try avoiding building the service provider multiple times, it can lead to some problem (for example multiple singleton services in the app lifetime)

Are I understand you corrent, you recommend not to use Di for ConfigureKestrel?

@DanielW. basically yes. At least I would try not to.

Hat about logging? Especially in case for ClientCertificateValidation? Is that possible without DI?

@DanielW. It depends on what you are actually using for logging. One approach can be creating a separate ServiceCollection just for building logging for the app startup code. Or building LoggerFactory manually.
